# How to fix Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 2, end 3, length 0 error?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, substring

I am writing a java program to use a `for` loop and substrings to return a palindrome, but I'm confused on what to put in the substring?

This is the code I used, and the error I received:

```java
String str2 = "";
for(int k = 2; k < sentence.length(); k++)
{
    String str3 = "";
    str3 = str2.substring(k , sentence.length()-1);
......
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 2, end 22, length 0
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I believe the issue is in the substring.

Comment: Your str2 is empty, but your index start with 2, substring function throws exception.

Comment: @Popeye what do you think i should do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `str2` is an empty string, so when you call `str2.substring(k, sentence.length()-1)`, it is trying to extract a substring from an index that does not exist, resulting in a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Here `str2` is of no use. And it looks like you are trying to extract a `substring` from the variable sentence using the variable `k` as the starting index and `sentence.length()-1` as the ending index.

```
for(int k = 0; k < sentence.length(); k++){
  String subString = sentence.substring(k, sentence.length());
  if(isPalindrome(subString)) {
    // do something
  }
}
```